# Log screensaver activity

Tags: windows, screensaver

as the title says I'd like to know is there is any way to see logs of the screensaver activity. Something like that:

02/02/2013 10:16:47 Screensaver started

02/02/2013 10:17:23 Screensaver stopped

I'm running Win7 Home premium 64 with ElectricSheep screensaver (awesome btw)

I'm not sure it's the right place to ask but I'm sure you computer gurus can help me :)
Thank you